# c# - How do I print a document without see the impression dialog

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to silent print a reciept :

```
    public void printReceipt()
    {
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument(); 

        printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt); 

        printDocument.Print(); // to print without preview

    }
```

but when I use this procedure i see a simplle form :

[impression form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVnIb.jpg)

**can I hide it or something like that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to create an instance of PrintController class and try to set your controller before printing your documents, as shown below:

```
    PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
    printDocument.PrintController = printController;
```